# How to implement const iterator?

Tags: c++, class, methods, iterator

In C++11 I am having issue implementing const iterator
int my class code (inside .cpp file) I have:

```
class MyClass{

public:

    class iterator;

    iterator begin() const;

    iterator end() const;

    class const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const;

    const_iterator end() const;
}
```

But as you may know, I can't implement 2 functions with the same signature, so how may I solve thus?

Comment: why do you make `iterator begin() const;` ? why is it `const`?

Comment: because I shouldn't make changes to the member of my class (this)

Comment: usually, you make changes using it like inserting, erasing ....

Comment: If u erase/insert some data, the pointer pointing your data may point to a new dynamic array.

Comment: Your class should have one const `begin()` and one non-const `begin()`. It makes no sense to have two const `begin()`. If you don't want a non-const `begin()` remove it completely.

Comment: @smith The shown class is ill-formed. If you don't make changes to it, then it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the function itself does not mutate the `this` object, if you want to have `begin()` both for `iterator` and for `const_iterator`, is to make the 2 function differs by the consteness, and so you should do something like this:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const ;
```

And let the compiler choose the best one (if `this` is const, that he will choose the second one, otherwise the first one)

And this actually make sense... if you have a `iterator`, you must have a instance of the class that is not-const,  otherwise you would be able to build a `iterator` with a const collection, and so you would be able to mutate a const collection, that is not what you want

Comment: But my professor said If a function won't make changes it should be declared as const or he will decrease points

Comment: maybe generic could be helpful here?

Comment: @smith and he is right, but in the `iterator` class you will probably have a constructor to call from the `begin` function, which will accept something like a pointer to your class, or something like that... that pointer will point to a instance not-const, and so if you mark the `begin` function const, you won't be able to call that constructor

Comment: @smith generics belongs to java... this is C++, and no, template won't help you in this case, or maybe, with a lot of boilerplate that you can avoid taking out that const

Comment: wouldn't this be considered as code duplication too?

Comment: @smith the `begin` function will have something like `return iterator(this,0)` as body, so i think you can consider it as not duplicate... maybe if you are using C++17 you can actually put everything in one function with a `if constexp`, but it's a little bit overkill for 1 line of code